# how to use CheckPoint For loop container in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, checkpoint

Long story short, checkpoint doesn't work for for-loop-container.

We're trying to use for loop containers when doing ETL process. For example we used @CounterNumber to loop, and EvalExpression is @CounterNumber <=5.

However, if it failed on the second round, even if the CheckPointFile captured that @CounterNumber = 2, but it's still restart the for loop from begining.

Does anyone know how to restart the for loop container from last failure?
I heard that we could use variables in InitExpression instead of static value, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Correct. Checkpoints are garbage. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/restart-packages-by-using-checkpoints?view=sql-server-ver15) calls it out a bit, although the [special case KB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/integration-services/ssis-checkpoints-not-honored-for-loop) is only going to apply to completed foreach loops not one actively running. The other issue I had with checkpoints in the 2005/2008 days was that they would invariably be corrupt when  your package did fail and once again, you have to restart the package from scratch. Very vexatious.

You can use a variable value in InitExpression as shown below

[image]

If you have defined the `InitExpression` as shown and you know that your package stopped executing while the value was 4 and thus, should restart the For Loop and initialize to 4, you can specify an initial value for @[User::IndexStart] when you run the package.

```
dtexec /file SO_69761840.dtsx /set \Package.Variables[User::IndexStart];4 /rep eiw
```

The `/SET` option there allows me to specify the initial value of a property in a Package so I provide an initial value of 4 to the Variable `User::IndexStart` that exists in the root Variables collection for our package. That variable path is all case sensitive, by the way.

This obviously requires you to identify what loop iteration you were on and does not tell the precursor steps to not fire. Very not automated but that might solve part of the problem you've encountered.

The lesson I learned with checkpoints is that they do not provide a silver bullet for package design. Instead, I harp that people need to think about restartability in their ETL and how it can be achieved with no cleanup or manual intervention required.
\Package.Variables[User::IndexStart]